# Struggling to understand object declaration code

Tags: java, object, declaration

I am working with hash maps and I have declared an array of buckets from type `SLLNode` that holds `MapEntry` objects:

```
private SLLNode<MapEntry<K, E>>[] buckets;
```

Now, I don't understand this code in the constructor:

```
buckets = (SLLNode<MapEntry<K, E>>[]) new SLLNode[m]; //where m is int, and it is
                                                      // the size of the array.
```

I can't understand this as well:

```
public SLLNode<MapEntry<K,E>> search(K targetKey) {

  int b = hash(targetKey);

  for (SLLNode<MapEntry<K,E>> curr = buckets[b]; curr != null; curr =
      curr.succ) {
    if (targetKey.equals(((MapEntry<K, E>) curr.element).key))
      return curr;   

    if (targetKey.equals(((MapEntry<K, E>) curr.element).key))
      return curr;
  }

  return null;
```

Precisely, I can't understand the logic of how the `(K targetKey)` is translated to `(MapEntry<K,E>)` and it is used in the equals method.

Comment: `buckets = (SLLNode<MapEntry<K, E>>[]) new SLLNode[m];` - which part of that confuses you? Can you point to specific syntax you don't understand, or possibly a specific reason you would expect this not to work?

Comment: I can't understand why (SLLNode<MapEntry<K, E>>[]) is used before new SLLNode[m]. I use it all the time but i don't know exactly what it is. Usually I have declared object like: Object O = new Object("something")

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand the logic of how the (K targetKey) is translated to (MapEntry)

It's not. The argument to `targetKey`'s `equals` method is

```
((MapEntry<K, E>) curr.element).key
```

This takes `curr.element`, casts it to a `MapEntry<K, E>`, and extracts the `key` field. Thus, the `equals` method of a `K` object is being called on another `K` object.